# Hide server IP for user's DNS record

Tags: domain-name-system, security, ip

I am starting a web hosting service using my own server. Are there any possible ways to cover my IP address for users to point their DNS? For example, my server's IP is **12.34.46.78** but I want the user to point their DNS record at **myserver.something.io**. If possible, what should I use?

Comment: What does it even mean? I mean, "for users to point their DNS"? You mean you want users in THEIR dns settings to be able to refer to your server by name? Does your server HAVE a domain name? If yes that is trivial - teach me basics of DNS trivial, read up on CNAME records. If not - off topic, not following business practices.

Comment: You cannot hide the IP address of a public service. If you could, nobody could reach it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for DNS CNAME record.

Answer (score 0):

You could let them create a CNAME record, but this is not allowed for the root domain (only for subdomains). Creating one for the root domain is not possible with most software and even if it is it will cause issues for your end users.

Point the root domain to your IP and add a CNAME record for their subdomain "www.example.com" that refers to "example.com".

If you are starting your own hosting service, you should do some research to learn more about this. If you are responsible for several websites, something goes wrong, and you have no idea what and why, you will have a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone should always use names. Easier for users, static even if IP changes, and enables name based virtual hosts. Insert AAAA and A records into DNS, and have users use those.

IP addresses, the answer from those DNS queries, cannot be hidden. If you are not comfortable publishing IP addresses and securing your services, do not start your own hosting service. Use someone else's hosting instead, plenty to choose from.